# Diophantine equations - how to go about it?

Tags: diophantine-equations

What are the methods of solving such tasks?

For example:

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+y-z=100\\
y^2+x-z=124
\end{cases}
$$

What first?

Comment: To take any $z$. And substitute into the other equation. And to turn out. $$(y-x)(y+x-1)=24$$  It remains to consider all of factorizing.

Comment: Give the domain of $x,y,z$. It is necessary for equations. Diophantine is not enough to understand integer unknowns.

Comment: x , y, z are natural